# Auditd to capture user runing command

Tags: logging, rsyslog

I have a audit watch/rule that logs every command executed, but it dose not mention/logs which user executed the command!

Do we have any workaround for that?

Comment: did you mean bash history in home directory it save all user executed commands

Comment: no, not the bash history, the actual commands for example, a user puppet cat /etc/shadow and it will log cat /etc/shadow not the user name executed the command.

Comment: var/log stores all loges

Comment: Yes, but not the executed commands !!